# Jquery Swipe without jQuery mobile library

Tags: jquery, touch, swipe

I know that this subject has been covered extensively on Stackoverflow but I cannot find a definitive answer.

I am successfully detecting if the client device is a touch screen:

```
if(!!('ontouchstart' in window)){

     // detect swipe

}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to detect a swipe/hover over an element. Please note that I want to be able to do this without the jquery mobile library.

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k77aC/9/

Thank you in advance,

Alan.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's just jQuery mobile which you don't want to use, try [hammer js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) which is lightweight and has a lot of options.

If however you're completely opposed to using any library at all have a look at the different touch events available:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events

Comment: Thanks hammer.js looks perfect for my needs!

Comment: I don't seem to be able to detect a swipe or tap using hammer.js: $('.myElement').hammer().on("tap", ".nested_el", function(event) {
           alert('yes');
             });

Comment: I fixed it by referencing the id rather than the class